# Connection String in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I am trying to connect to a database with my connection string and recieve the following error when trying to connect to the database. For intergrated Security I user SSID so I don't have to enter a username and password. Also, the database resides on the same machine and was created inside VS2010. I can connect to the db without a problem using the SqlDataSource, but I am looking to start writing my own connection strings.

```
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string source = "server=(local)" + "integrated security=SSPI;" + "Connect     Timeout=30; "  + "database=Name";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(source);
        conn.Open();

        conn.Close();

    }
```

The Error I get is this:

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following syntax as connection string:

```
string source = "Data Source=Server Address;Initial Catalog=Database Name;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
```

Where Server Address should be localhost or .\SQLExpress

Hope thats correct. I have'nt installed a vs for testing

Comment: Thanks, instead of using server=(local) I switched to Data Source with the full address. If anyone else tries this make sure you use double backslashes in the address. For example, C:\\MyDoc\\database.mdf.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `;` after the server name.

Why are you concatenating all the parts of the connection string if they do not change? It makes it more difficult to read.

Try this:

```
string source = "server=(local);integrated security=SSPI;ConnectTimeout=30;database=Name";
```

Comment: Your absolutley correct, I was but now I am back to my old error which is.

Comment: Cannot open database "Name" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'X\xm'.

Comment: I thought if I use windows inegrated security the credentials that were supplied at logon are passed to SQL Server. Which allows me to remove the uid and pwd and insert Integrated Security=SSPI.

Comment: @jpavlov: Is your database called "Name", really?

Comment: @jpavlov - correct, so long as the database `Name` exists and the account your are logging in as has permissions to use it (Security/Users section).

Answer (score 2):

You need a semicolon after (local)

`string source = "server=(local);" + "integrated security=SSPI`

I notice you tagged the question with asp.net
by default asp.net runs under a system account, when you are using integrated security then that account is trying to access your database, it probably doesn't have permission.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx) for some information.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=VS.100).aspx

That will probably make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to SQL Server from C#.NET, you need to create a connection string such as below:

```
private SqlConnection connection;
private string connectionString =
    @"Server=(local);Database=Embedding_SQL_Test;User ID=sa;Password=123";
connection = new SqlConnection( connectionString );
```

Next, you use the SqlConnection object created above to create a 'SqlCommand', as shown below:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "select * from Customer where CustomerID = @Cid",
    connection);
```

The SQL query shown here can be replaced by a `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` queries etc.

Next to execute the SQL queries in the database, you use the following methods:
`ExecuteReader` - to execute `SELECT` queries
`ExecuteNonQuery` - to execute `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, and `SET` statements.

This is a very short description of how to connect to SQL Server database from C# and execute SQL queries in the database.
For details about the connection string, the methods and their parameters check the following link: ( http://www.shahriarnk.com/Shahriar-N-K-Research-Embedding-SQL-in-C-Sharp-Java.html )
Here you will also find details about how to pass parameters to the SQL queries as well as calling stored procedures and much more.